# How to use property-placeholder for file on filesystem

Tags: java, spring

We used to have a way to load properties from a file on the classpath:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myConfigFile.properties" />
```

and it worked great. But now we want to load properties from a specific file on the system that is NOT in the classpath. We wanted to be able to dynamically load the file, so we are using a Java environment variable to populate it. I'll give a simple example below:

In Java:

```java
  System.setProperty("my.prop.file", "/path/to/myConfigFile.properties");
```

In Spring XML:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="${my.prop.file}" />
```

I've also tried it this way, thanks to an idea from Luciano:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="prop" />

<util:properties id="prop" location="reso"/>

<bean id="reso" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${my.prop.file}" />
</bean>
```

Everything I've tried has failed. No matter what I set my.prop.file to. Greatest hits include:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/path/to/myConfigFile.properties" />
(ClassNotFoundException: .path.to.myConfigFile.properties)

<context:property-placeholder location="file:/path/to/myConfigFile.properties" />
(ClassNotFoundException: file:.path.to.myConfigFile.properties)

<context:property-placeholder location="file:///path/to/myConfigFile.properties" />
(ClassNotFoundException: file:...path.to.myConfigFile.properties)
```

How do you use property-placeholders with a location that is on the file system and NOT on the classpath? We are using Spring 3.0.5.

It turns out there was a problem with the script running the Java program that loads the spring file. Thank you for helping. I am going to request that this question be deleted, as the original code works after all.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: BTW Strongly disagree w/ this being closed.

Comment: Disagree with the closing too. I came here after some googling and it descibes the exact question I have...

Comment: Me too -  I don't understand why this was closed with a "too localized" category ? Its seems fairly general to me ?

Comment: You can always click "reopen" to vote to re-open the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this way?

```xml
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="prop" />

<util:properties id="prop" location="reso"/>

<bean id="reso" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="/yourpathandfile" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Can I put in the Java environment variable for the value="/yourpathandfile"? I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The property is getting passed through, but the same errors happen. Thank you for your help, though. Is this not possible?

Comment: what if you hardcode ${my.prop.file} with the real path just to see if that works?

Comment: Shouldn't that be properties-ref="my.prop.file"?  Or am I misunderstanding?  I don't understand what "prop" is in this context.

Comment: @Marvo prop is the id defined in the second line where it says util:properties

Answer (score 16):

This did work for me:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:/path/to/myConfigFile.properties" />
```

But this (interestingly) did not:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="#{ systemProperties['foo'] }" />
```

I got

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/#{ systemProperties['foo'] }]
```

You're not going to be able to use a property placeholder `${..}` with the definition of a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.   It's the chicken before the egg.

You can always subclass PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and have it do whatever you want (for example, call `setLocations()` in a `@PostConstruct` method.  Then, instead of using `<context:property-placeholder>`, use:

```
<bean class="com.foo.MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>
```

Comment: I thought that the expression language allowed for that, as argued in [this article about managing property files with spring](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring/). I'll try to understand what needs to be subclassed in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer so that it can figure out how to dynamically load a property file. It seemed such a simple idea and it seems so convoluted now with Spring.